# How to build recursion to calculate intermediate points if the distribution law is known

Tags: c++, recursion

Interstage temperatures

[image: 1]

There is a problem: calculate interstage temperatures of the thermoelectric module. Each interstage temperature could be defined by neighboring temperatures as Ti=pow(Ti+1 * Ti-1, 0.5). The temperatures on the top and at the bottom are known. I'm trying to calculate them by recursive function but unsuccessfully.

```
double multistage::t_i(double tcold, double thot, int stage) {

if (0 == stage)
    return tcold;

if (stages.size() - 1 == stage)                         //stages -- vector containing all stages
    return thot;

return pow(t_i(tcold, thot, stage + 1) * t_i(tcold, thot, stage - 1), .5);}
```

But it does not work. Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Frankly the definition seems bogus because T(i) depends upon itself. To calculate T(i) you need to calculate T(i+1), but to calculate T(i+1) you need to calculate T(i).

Comment: `t_i(..., 3)` calls `t_i(..., 2)` and `t_i(..., 4)`. Both of these call `t_i(..., 3)` again. You have an infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that calculation in the chosen way is impossible. I should know two sequent temperatures for the calculation of the next one taking into account the distribution law.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a recursive function to calculate all the T<sub>i</sub>, these could be calculated in a loop<sup>(1)</sup>, using the analitycal solution of the non-linear system of equations.

```
void fill_with_powers(std::span<double> a)
{
  auto analitycal = [low = a.front(), high = a.back(), N = a.size() - 1.0](double i){
    return std::pow(low, (N - i) / N) * std::pow(high, i / N);
  };
  for (size_t i{1}; i + 1 < a.size(); ++i)
    a[i] = analitycal(i);
}
```

When such a solution is not known, a common method to solve this type of problems is to start from a first guess and iteratively refine it (hopefully) converging to the the solution<sup>(2)</sup>.

If you want to use recursion, for the sake of it, you could use<sup>(3)</sup> a divide and conquer technique.

```
void fill_rec(std::span<double> a)
{
  if ( a.size() <= 2 )
    return;
  
  size_t m{ a.size() / 2 };
  if ( a.size() % 2 )
  {
    a[m] = geometric_mean(a.front(), a.back());
    
    fill_rec(a.first(m + 1));
    fill_rec(a.last(m + 1));
  }
  else
  {
    auto [i, j] = [](double k, double n){
      return std::pair{ (k - 1) / n, k / n };
    }(m, a.size() - 1);

    auto analitycal = [low = a.front(), high = a.back()](double e_low, double e_high) {
      return std::pow(low, e_low) * std::pow(high, e_high);
    };

    a[m - 1] = analitycal(j, i);
    a[m] = analitycal(i, j);

    fill_rec(a.first(m));
    fill_rec(a.last(m));
  }
}
```

---

1. https://godbolt.org/z/WhjWvEMsh
2. https://godbolt.org/z/dfxfzTv6o
3. https://godbolt.org/z/j1j6dPPhc